# PHP fopen does not working with directory variable

Tags: php, fopen

I have a php code that it creates a random name, then creates the directory, and then I need to create and write a text file inside the directory. 
It creates the directory, but nothing when it need to create the text file.
This is what I have:

This create the random name

```
$letra1 = chr(rand(65,90));
$letra2 = chr(rand(97,122));
$letra3 = chr(rand(65,90));
$letra4 = chr(rand(97,122));
```

This join all the characters:

```
$letras = $letra1 . $letra2 . $letra3 . $letra4;
```

This creates de directory:

```
mkdir("a/$letras", 777);
```

And here, where i think I have the problem, the fopen:

```
$archt = fopen("a/$letras/text.txt", "w") or die("");
$txt = "";
fclose($archt);
```

I think it isn't a perms problem, I have given 777 to all directories...

I have tried a lot of stuf that I have been searched from stackoverflow but nothing is working for me and don't know what it will be?

Comment: And you've turned on full PHP error reporting to debug this? `ini_set('display_errors', true);  error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: are all in the same page?

Comment: Change the 777 to 0777 and see if it changes the results.
The mkdir refirs to chmod() for mode information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php The mode requires the leading 0 according to the chmod() function in order to avoid unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment to the questions: you are passing a decimal to the mkdir function as apposed to passing an octal which is what is required. The permissions are not being set correctly as a result.

With the interpreter (php) setup correctly for a development environment your code produced the following error:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(a/DeOq/text.txt): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in /home/dave/Desktop/test/test.php on line 11

To avoid having to dig through comments for details:

The mkdir() documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php refers to the chmod() directory for explanation of mode. Mode is required to be an octal

> Note that mode is not automatically assumed to be an octal value, so to ensure the expected operation, you need to prefix mode with a zero (0). Strings such as "g+w" will not work properly.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

In addition to changing 777 to 0777 in the mkdir() function, ensure that the "a" directory actually exists as the mkdir() function will not make a directory "tree". "a" is required to already exist in order to make a directory under it.

This code is tested and works:

```
<?php
$letra1 = chr(rand(65,90));
$letra2 = chr(rand(97,122));
$letra3 = chr(rand(65,90));
$letra4 = chr(rand(97,122));

$letras = $letra1 . $letra2 . $letra3 . $letra4;

mkdir("a/$letras", 0777);

$archt = fopen("a/$letras/text.txt", "w") or die("Death");
$txt = "";
fclose($archt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permissions to the sub-directories too.

```
<?php
    $letra1 = chr(rand(65,90));
    $letra2 = chr(rand(97,122));
    $letra3 = chr(rand(65,90));
    $letra4 = chr(rand(97,122));
    $letras = $letra1 . $letra2 . $letra3 . $letra4;


    mkdir("a/$letras", 0777, true); //third parameter is important if you want to add perms recursively 


    $archt = fopen("a/".$letras."/text.txt", "w")or die(print_r(error_get_last(),true));

    $txt = "";

    fclose($archt);

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the `"$letras"` hides the variable

```
$dirLocation = "a/" . $letras;

mkdir($dirLocation, 0777);

$fileLocation = $dirLocation . "/text.txt";

$archt = fopen($fileLocation, "w") or die("");

$txt = "";

fclose($archt);
```

Comment: How is this different from the current code? Double-quotes evaluates the variable, so in essence looks the same as your code.